# How to properly apply stroke for non-latin characters in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, text, nsattributedstring

I'm working on a project to apply text attributes to UIlabel text. I'm using the common NSAttributedString keys to basically apply strokeColor and strokeWidth and foregroundColor to generate the desired outlining effect. The problem appears on non-latin characters, such as Arabic, where letters are individual highlighted instead of the entire work. The letter typically are connected in Arabic, unlink english were letters are spaced. I'm attaching the example I'm working on with a screenshot of the issue and the desired outcome. I would appreciate your support and suggestions.

```
let quote = "الكتابة على الصور بخطوط جميلة"
        //let font = UIFont.systemFon.selft(ofSize: 50)
        let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
               .strokeColor: UIColor.green,
                .strokeWidth: -3.0,
                .foregroundColor: UIColor.red,
                .font: UIFont(name: "Georgia-Bold", size: 40)!,
        ]
        let attributedQuote = NSAttributedString(string: quote, attributes: attributes) 
        TextLabel.attributedText = attributedQuote
```

outcome with issue:

[image]

desired outcome:

[image]

Comment: Anyone tried core graphics with cgContext to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Taking a quick look at this - and comparing it to similar output from css - I think you'll need to use two labels layers on top of each other.

Give this a try:

```
    let backLabel = UILabel()
    let frontLabel = UILabel()

    backLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    frontLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    view.addSubview(backLabel)
    view.addSubview(frontLabel)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        backLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100.0),
        backLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
        backLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),

        frontLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backLabel.topAnchor),
        frontLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backLabel.leadingAnchor),
        frontLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backLabel.trailingAnchor),
    ])

    let quote = "الكتابة على الصور بخطوط جميلة"

    var attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
        .strokeColor: UIColor.green,
        .strokeWidth: 12.0,
        .foregroundColor: UIColor.red,
        .font: UIFont(name: "Georgia-Bold", size: 40)!,
    ]
    var attributedQuote = NSAttributedString(string: quote, attributes: attributes)
    backLabel.attributedText = attributedQuote

    attributes = [
        .strokeColor: UIColor.green,
        .strokeWidth: 0,
        .foregroundColor: UIColor.red,
        .font: UIFont(name: "Georgia-Bold", size: 40)!,
    ]
    attributedQuote = NSAttributedString(string: quote, attributes: attributes)
    frontLabel.attributedText = attributedQuote
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I tried this option and if works as expected! Saved me lot of time buddy! Thanks again